# How to read the readonly status on psycopg2?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

On `psycopg2`, I can put the connection on read only mode with:

```
connection.set_session(readonly=True)
```

But how do I know if the connection is in read-only mode?

Answer (score 3):

Starting in psycopg2 v2.7, you can use the [connection.readonly](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/connection.html#connection.readonly) attribute to determine whether the connection is in read-only mode (`True`) or read/write mode (`False`).

If you're running an earlier version, you can execute the query:

```
SHOW transaction_read_only;
```

Which will have the value `'on'` for read-only mode, or `'off'` for read/write mode.

Comment: Note that `connection.readonly` can also be `None` which the docs say means "use the default configured for the server by `default_transaction_read_only`". I think if you set that via `connection.set_session(readonly=True)`, it will just set the `.readonly` attribute, but maybe you could do it in SQL and it'll still be `None`. Also, if the database is read-only, you won't know without the `SHOW ...` query.

Answer (score -1):

Try it:

```
conn.set_session(readonly=True)
try:
    cursor.execute('create table xyz (a int)')
    cursor.execute('drop table xyz')
except psycopg2.InternalError, e:
    print e.message
```

Output:

```
cannot execute CREATE TABLE in a read-only transaction
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! But the user does not have permission to create tables and I do not know the database structure. Is there a generic way to do this test?